# Internet (wired) needs to reconnect after blank-screen

Tags: internet

I use Ubuntu 20.04, all updates and upgrades installed, at every installation it is the same thing:

After 5 minutes, 'blank-screen' is applied - good! screen-saver,energy-saver.

I move the mouse, desktop appears, and then, the internet (I use wired) is disconnected, and needs to reconnect.

It's not 'once in a while', it's not 'a bad installation', it's constant - that's how Ubuntu is built.

Why? I want to return to my computer and see that nothing has changed. - Internet was connected before blank-screen mode, and it's connected after it as well.

- Vast majority of repositories downloaded at Ubuntu installation process, are from the .il (Israeli) source, probably. [because it asks for 'Time Zone', and the answer is Jerusalem]. It Has done a problem before [= being unable to install WineHQ correctly].

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The screen blank probably isn't causing this (test with `xset dpms force off` and then hit a key as soon as the screen blanks and check your network).  Most likely the longer idle time is making the whole computer go to sleep and the network driver doesn't wake up properly.

Use `ip addr` to find the name of your wired interface, then `ethtool -i en0` (replace en0 with your interface name) to find out what driver it uses.  Add the name of the driver to your question.  There may be a module option (check with `modinfo driver..`) that can be added to disable sleep mode for the driver.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
Is it normal, or is it only My comp?

I use an ASUS laptop, about 5 years old.

What seemed strange to me, is that in Windows this problem never existed. So just out of curiosity - what's the difference?

(It's not a Big thing, you need to wait for 15 sec. but I thought it to be an error. Appearantly, it is not. Thank you all.)

Comment: Specific network chipsets have both driver and hardware bugs involving waking up from sleep.  So it both is and isn't your computer.  :)